# a standard blowfish API for C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, blowfish

I have searched the Internet but it seems as though there are many implementations, some of which do not work correctly, is there a standard or working API  for C++ i can use to decrypt blowfish cyphered strings?

thanks in advance

Comment: I liked [libmcrypt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/2.5.8/) Should be part of popular Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) crypto library has [blowfish support](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/blowfish.html). It is recommended to use the [OpenSSL EVP](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/evp.html) system rather than the calls directly.

Answer (score 6):

[`Crypto++`](http://www.cryptopp.com/) has [`Blowfish`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_blowfish.html) implementation